# Show block in particular nodes having some string in title

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a block and I need to show this block only in some situations.
For example if title of node includes "abc", block will be visible else it won't.
From visibility settings of block I use this code snippet:

```
<?php
$match = FALSE;

$url = request_uri();
if (strpos($url, "myword")) {
  $match = TRUE;
}
?>
```

I'm sure that "myword" is included in full URL of node.
I tried to debug it by adding "echo $url" but it didn't write this line into page.

How can I solve this?

edit: in last line i forgot to add "return $match;" which returned always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (strpos($url, 'myword') !== FALSE) {
  $match = TRUE;
}
```

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the substring.

So if "myword" is at the start of the URI string `strpos()` will return `0`, and since `0 == FALSE` in terms of a conditional, it will fail.

I've just tested your code and it works fine with the slight change.